# Initialize templated type to "zero"

Tags: c++, templates, function

If I have a template function, say one that calculates an average by summing up the elements in a container of type T holding things of T::value_type, how do I elegantly initialize the sum with a zero?

Suppose the underlying type is not a plain old data type.  It could be a complex variable, or some other as yet uncoded mathematical entity which has some form of a zero.

Something more elegant than

```
T::value_type sum = 0;
```

Then hoping for the best cast.

Comment: What's inelegant about `= 0`? You could do `T::value_type sum(0);` to remove the copy-initialization but that's probably not significantly different.

Comment: Confusing confusing question.
Why dont you expand, form complete and full sentences. Dont be verbose. Just give exactly what you are trying to do...

Comment: Both those sentences are complete and correct English sentence, with the possible exception of the capital T on Then.

Comment: This question is just baffling. You want to initialize something to zero, but you're unhappy with... initializing it to zero? Why do you perceive this as a problem at all?

Comment: @Charles your alternative also considers explicit ctors.

Comment: Edited to perhaps make more clear.  Honestly thought this would be a relatively simple syntactical mechanism that I'd missed.

Comment: @drb: Is there a constraint on the types that you use with your template that allows you to know how to make a value that is the "some form of a zero" that you refer to other than converting `0` to the type?

Comment: @drb: If your "yet undetermined type" permits addition and division, as you require to form your average, then it should have a notion of zero, namely the neutral element for the addition, and then it should be constructible to that zero value.

Comment: Thanks, for all your comments, I know what I need to do now.  The reference to accumulate below was particularly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you would like better

```
T::value_type sum = T::value_type();
```

Comment: Although value initialization is often the same or equivalent to zero initialization, if the intent is to initialize with a zero surely this is - if anything - less desirable than `= 0;`.

Comment: I know, after all I've nothing against assigning something to 0, but maybe it was relevant for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

```
typename T::value_type sum = typename T::value_type(); //or simply = 0;
```

The important point here is : `typename` is must. If you don't write it, a Standard-conformant compiler would give compilation error.

Answer (score 2):

Take the initial value as a parameter:

```
template<typename In, typename T>
T accumulate(In first, In last, T init);
```

That happens to be the signature of `std::accumulate()` from `<numeric>`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have the user provide the initial 'empty' value or you can take the first element as the initial value, and then perform the addition from the second element on.  It results in only using the default constructor if you pass it an empty list.  Otherwise, it uses the first element as an initial sum, and goes from there.

```
template <class Iterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type average_elements(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
   typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value_type;
   if (first == last) {
      return value_type(); // Best you can do
   }  
   value_type sum = *first++;
   size_t n = 1;
   while (first != last) {
       sum += *first++;
       ++n;
   }
   return sum / n;
}
```